# Creating a loop that matches time interval to raw data

Tags: r, time

I have a dataset that contains timestamps of Uber pickups in New York. I would like to add an additional column to the table which will contain the timestamps formatted to 15 minute intervals. For example:

The raw timestamps:

`4/1/2014 21:46:00 4/1/2014 21:47:00`

The expected output in 15 minute intervals:

`2014-04-01 21:45:00 UTC--2014-04-01 22:00:00 UTC`.

I have managed to achieve the conversion of the raw timestamps to a 15 minute interval timestamp by doing the following:

```
library(lubridate)
#formatting Date.Time to POSIXct 
uber1$Date.Time <- format(as.POSIXct(uber1$Date.Time ,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
time_int<-seq(ISOdatetime(2014,4,1,0,0,0), ISOdatetime(2014,7,10,0,0,0), by=(60*15))
time_int <- format(as.POSIXct(time_int ,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
interval_object <- int_diff(time_int)
```

My issue now is that I cannot match the transformed timestamps back to their original timestamp. How would I match the raw timestamp to the interval object?

Comment: Can you add a small reproducible example using `dput` and show expected output based on that? Read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another interval with the date time in your data frame and ask which 15 min interval it falls into:

```
library(lubridate)
set.seed(100)
uber1 = data.frame(
Date.Time = ISOdatetime(2014,4,1,0,0,0)+70*86400*runif(100)
)
uber1$Date.Time <- format(as.POSIXct(uber1$Date.Time ,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))

idx = sapply(interval(uber1$Date.Time,uber1$Date.Time),
function(i)which(i %within% interval_object)[1])

uber1$matching_interval = interval_object[idx]

            Date.Time                                matching_interval
1 2014-04-22 13:02:49 2014-04-22 13:00:00 UTC--2014-04-22 13:15:00 UTC
2 2014-04-19 00:53:23 2014-04-19 00:45:00 UTC--2014-04-19 01:00:00 UTC
3 2014-05-09 15:54:06 2014-05-09 15:45:00 UTC--2014-05-09 16:00:00 UTC
4 2014-04-04 22:43:25 2014-04-04 22:30:00 UTC--2014-04-04 22:45:00 UTC
5 2014-05-03 19:09:46 2014-05-03 19:00:00 UTC--2014-05-03 19:15:00 UTC
6 2014-05-04 20:44:05 2014-05-04 20:30:00 UTC--2014-05-04 20:45:00 UTC
```

The above is slow when you have a large data.frame and many intervals. A better way is to cut it straight away:

```
# a function to include start and end of period, and spacing
cut_func = function(tid,start,end,len){
return(cut(c(start,tid,end),len)[-c(1,length(tid)+1)])
}

set.seed(100)
uber1 = data.frame(
    Date.Time = ISOdatetime(2014,4,1,0,0,0)+70*86400*runif(100)
    )

uber1$interval = cut_func(
uber1$Date.Time,
start=ISOdatetime(2014,4,1,0,0,0),
end=ISOdatetime(2017,4,1,0,0,0),
len="15 min")
```

And this gives you the start of the 15min interval the time your data frame matches:

```
            Date.Time            interval
1 2014-04-22 13:02:49 2014-04-22 13:00:00
2 2014-04-19 00:53:23 2014-04-19 00:45:00
3 2014-05-09 15:54:06 2014-05-09 15:45:00
4 2014-04-04 22:43:25 2014-04-04 22:30:00
5 2014-05-03 19:09:46 2014-05-03 19:00:00
6 2014-05-04 20:44:05 2014-05-04 20:30:00
```

Comment: You're welcome :) If it solves your problem, you can consider accepting the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. Just letting you know since you are new to SO . Have a good weekend!

Comment: Can you also help me to understand how do I group by the time intervals and summarize how many rides were in each interval? I understand that dplyr would be helpful here

Comment: Yes using the example above, you can do uber1 %>% count(interval) or simply table(uber1$interval)